# How can I upgrade alien extension on lua for windows?

Tags: lua

I have installed Lua for windows 5.1.4-40 and it comes with alien 0.4.1.

I want to upgrade alien to 0.5.0, and couldn't figure out a way to do it.

I have luarocks installed with lua for windows, and I have tried to use it.

*luarocks.bat install alien*

However, I got an error message saying:

*Error: Failed unpacking rockk file: C:\tmp\luarocks_....*

Comment: Ask on Lua mailing list for a new LfW release with an upgrade. You're likely to get it.

Comment: @alexander-gladysh: Not lately. They've been too stuck on how to package it going forward to put out an interim release.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I got the error was that I didn't run it as Administrator, although my account has admin permission.
To solve this problem, I ran cygwin as administrator, and luarocks worked perfectly.

Comment: You should mark this answer as the solution (click the checkmark to the left).